# Mouseenter function displays buttons and images over a div but hovering on these breaks mouseleave function

Tags: jquery, mouseleave, mouseenter

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="object1">
    <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/682110/person1.png" width="100" height="100" />        
</div>  

<a class="button" href="#" >Register</a>

<div id="object-bg"></div>

</div>
```

JS

```
$("#object-bg").mouseenter(function () {
  $("#object1").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
  $(".button").delay(500).fadeIn(100);
});

$("#object-bg").mouseleave(function () {
  $("#object1, .button").css("display", "none");
});
```

I have set up a basic demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jesseyuen/4FPfG/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the button and user image is not the part **#object-bg**, hovering them will result in triggers of mouse leave event

use this html instead

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="object-bg">
  <div id="object1">  
    <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/682110/person1.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </div>    
  <a class="button" href="#" >Register</a>       
 </div>
</div>
```

now you can right the css again for re-positioning them here is the [**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4FPfG/5/#update)

Comment: hover get triggerd on both mouseEnter and mouseLeave events

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="object1">

        <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/682110/person1.png" width="100" height="100" />

    </div>  



    <div id="object-bg"> <a class="button" href="#" >Register</a></div>

</div>
```

updated fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/4FPfG/6/

Thanks,

Siva